# How to put if/else condition into ng-href

Tags: angularjs

How to put a condition into `ng-href`?

For example if `*popup==='1'` dont redirect it at all, else redirect it to `surveyUrl` (holds a URL). 
I tried this code but it doesn't seem to work, it redirects me to an url like this `/%7B%7B`.

What am i doing wrong?

```
<a ng-href={{ popup==='1' ?  '#': surveyUrl }}
```

Comment: Hard to tell with all the missing information, but try to enclose your link properly `ng-href="{{...}}"`

Comment: Please encapsulate it with ' or ". That could be your issue

Comment: yep, that was the issue. thank you :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are missing quotes:

```
<a ng-href="{{ popup ==='1' ?  '#': surveyUrl }}"> test</a>
```

Comment: thanks, it worked. do u know how to not redirect at all? cuz putting "#" sends me to homepage

Comment: If you replace '#' with '' will it work for you? Otherwise I suggest you to use `ng-click` instead and put that logic into a function